# Plot a cut of a ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I have a bunch of points, e.g. minimal example:

```
x = {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0.5}, {-1, -1, 0.5}, {-1, 1, 0.5}, {1, -1, 
   0.5}}
```

and I am plotting them as a `ListPlot3D`:

```
ListPlot3D[x]
```

Giving me this:

[image]

--

What I would like is a **1D plot taken as a cut of this**, like so:

[image]

The issue here being that there are no points at x = 0, so I'd have to take a projection on that plane? Or is there an interpolation method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Interpolation` directly on your original data:

```
x = {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0.5}, {-1, -1, 0.5}, {-1, 1, 0.5}, {1, -1,  0.5}};
iF = Quiet @ Interpolation[x];

Row[{ListPlot3D[x, ImageSize -> 300, PlotLabel -> "ListPlot3D", 
   MeshFunctions -> {# &}, Mesh -> {{-.5, 0, .5}}, MeshStyle -> Thick],
  Plot3D[iF[u, v], {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   ImageSize -> 300, PlotLabel -> "Plot3D", 
   MeshFunctions -> {# &}, Mesh -> {{-.5, 0, .5}}, MeshStyle -> Thick]}]
```

[image]

```
Row[Plot[iF[#, t], {t, -1, 1}, ImageSize -> 220,     
    PlotRange -> {.5, 1}, PlotLabel -> Row[{"x = ", #}]] & /@ {-.5,  0, .5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks, but I cannot seem to be able to apply to my set of points, which is quite dense..

Comment: @SuperCiocia, can you post an example of a small data set that shows the issue?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3bvjKgzD

Comment: @SuperCiocia, the error message "_Interpolation::indp: There are duplicated abscissa points in..._"   suggests that need to eliminate the duplicate abscissa (e.g., `iF =Interpolation@DeleteDuplicates[data, #[[;; 2]] == #2[[;; 2]] &]`) for `Interpolation` two work.

Answer (score 4):

You can interpolate

```
x = {{#, #2}, #3} & @@@ {
  {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0.5}, {-1, -1, 0.5}, {-1, 1, 0.5}, {1, -1, 0.5}
};

f = Interpolation[x];

Plot[f[0, y], {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]